# Send JWT token using AWS Android SDK

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, mobile, jwt

We have some API Gateway endpoints. Each endpoint is protected with a Custom Authorizer (CA). This CA inspect the HTTP call and verify the presence of the `Authorization` header. This header must contains an OpenId Connect token (a simple JWT token), so the CA can inspect it and make some checks and validations.

When we use Postman to invoke the endpoint, it works without a problem, since we can setup the right headers.

The problems start to raises when we use the generated Android SDK to make the same call, since each attempt to make the call sends an AWS4 signature as header. We can figure out how to send `Authorization` header with JWT.

We get what we need by extending ApiClientFactory class and adding the header in an explicit ways:

```
public class CustomApiClientFactory extends ApiClientFactory {

    private String LOGIN_NAME = "a.provider.com";
    private AWSCredentialsProvider provider;

    @Override
    public ApiClientFactory credentialsProvider(AWSCredentialsProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
        return super.credentialsProvider(provider);
    }

    @Override
    ApiClientHandler getHandler(String endpoint, String apiName) {
        final Signer signer = provider == null ? null : getSigner(getRegion(endpoint));

        // Ensure we always pass a configuration to the handler
        final ClientConfiguration configuration =  new ClientConfiguration();

        return new ApiClientHandler(endpoint, apiName, signer, provider, null, configuration) {
            @Override
            Request<?> buildRequest(Method method, Object[] args) {
                Request<?> request = super.buildRequest(method, args);
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + ((CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider) provider).getLogins().get(LOGIN_NAME));
                return request;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Even if it works, it sounds to me like a workaround. There is some known best practice in facing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway allows the request to be defined for each method just add a HTTP request header in the method request and the generated SDK will have a field to specify the header.

Console:
[image: console view that allows adding header]

Generated Android SDK:

```
@com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Operation(path = "/companies", method = "GET")
CompanyList companiesGet(
        @com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Parameter(name = "x-vendor-authorization", location = "header")
        String xVendorAuthorization,
        @com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Parameter(name = "continuationToken", location = "query")
        String continuationToken,
        @com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Parameter(name = "pageSize", location = "query")
        String pageSize,
        @com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Parameter(name = "properties", location = "query")
        String properties);
```

SDK call:

```
client.companiesGet("abc123AuthToken", "continueToken1", "20", "prop1");
```